Directors had some kind of a bet - there was a cool scene of samurai/ninjas fighting in the dark
I am looking for a movie I saw about 10-15 years ago.
I still know there were two directors who had some kind of bet or competition, but I don't remember specifics.
One scene that I still remember is a long fighting scene between two samurai or ninjas in some kind of a tower/castle/temple in the dark. You could not see the action except for sparks when the swords smashed into each other and some lighting from a thunderstorm.
I would really like to watch this movie again, and learn more about the bet between the directors and the other movies that were produced because of the bet.

Aragami (2003), which was created on a bet and contains the scene you've mentioned. From IMDb:

A raging god of battle and a master samurai duke it out in a series of sword fights in a remote temple.

From a review:

Director Ryuhei Kitamura, now famous thanks to the big success of "Versus" and "Azumi", was challenged to make this experimental film in an odd bet with producer Shinya Kawai and fellow filmmaker Yukihiko Tsutsumi. Named the "Duel" project, Kawai challenged the two filmmakers to each create a feature length movie with only two actors, battling in one setting and filmed entirely in one week.

Near the end, the samurai and the God kill the candle-light and then all we see are flashes of light as their swords clash. Here's the trailer (rather low quality, sorry):



